# Función siguiente día disponible PHP

Tags: php, array, funciones, date

El tema que elegí no es muy claro, les explico:

Deseo realizar una función que me arroje el siguiente día disponible, a partir de una fecha, y validada con una matriz de días NO disponibles.

para nuestro caso el lunes será el día número 1 y domingo el día número 7.

lunes(1), martes(2), miércoles(3), jueves(4), viernes(5), sábado(6), domingo(7).

```
$mis_dias_no_disponibles = array(1,4,5,7);
```

Según la matriz, mis días no disponibles son lunes, jueves, viernes y domingos. Y si la fecha ingresada cae en esos días que la función la recorra hasta el siguiente día disponible.

Nuestra fecha ejemplo será: 
2018-05-31 (jueves y la matriz nos indica que es un día no disponible ya que es el día número 4).

```
echo "FECHA: ".funcion_fechas('2018-05-31',$mis_dias_no_disponibles);
```

El siguiente día disponible en este ejemplo sería el día sábado y el resultado esperado debería ser este:

```
FECHA: 2018-06-02
```

Y cuándo se ingrese una fecha disponible, que la función la deje igual.

```
echo "FECHA: ".funcion_fechas('2018-06-02',$mis_dias_no_disponibles);
FECHA: 2018-06-02
```

Espero no haber enredado con mi explicación y de antemano les agradezco mucho la ayuda ya que el manejo con fechas es algo que me causa gran dolor de cabeza. Gracias!.

Comment: Haz un while sumando un dia en cada iteracion hasta que se cumpla la regla y luego retorna el ultimo dia.

Comment: No lo había considerado, voy a la práctica. ¡Gracias!.

Comment: Prueba con recursividad, la función se llama a sí misma mientras se cumpla que el día es uno no válido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una función recursiva, por la cual te compare el día de la semana de la fecha que le pasas con los números del array:

**AVISO, con este método, hay que realizar un cambio, el domingo corresponde a '0', el resto es igual**

```
function funcion_fechas($fecha,$array_dias){
   // Sacamos el valor del día de la semana (domingo = 0 | sábado = 6)
   $day_of_week = date("w", strtotime($fecha));
   //aprovechamos la función php in_array(), que te devuelve true si encuentra el valor en la colección.
   if(in_array(intval($day_of_week),$array_dias)){
       // Si el valor es true, volver a intentar, sumando un día a la fecha
       $fecha_aux = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha, ' + 1 days'));
       return funcion_fechas($fecha_aux, $array_dias);
   }else{
       // Si el valor es false, te devuelve la fecha.
       return $fecha;
   }
}
```

Este método debería funcionarte bien. :)

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias nada más hice dos pequeños ajustes: el primero par convertirlo de lunes(1) a domingo(7) `$day_of_week = date("N", strtotime($fecha));` y `$fecha_aux = date('Y-m-d', strtotime ( '+1 day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) );` Espero sea de gran ayuda para muchos más.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro de que valga :)